# How can I pause a repeatForever Animation and the resume it in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a repeatForever Animation and I want pause animation, and then resume it later, but my code does not work, and they destroy the frames of current animation.

```
 struct HatchedShap: Shape {
    let dis: CGFloat
    var move: CGFloat

    var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { return move }
        set { move = newValue }
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        Path { path in
            
            for start in stride(from: 0, through: rect.height, by: dis) {
                
                let offset = start + (dis*move).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: dis)

                if (0.0...rect.height ~= offset) {
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY + offset))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + offset))
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

use case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var move: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            VStack {
                
                Text(String(describing: move)).bold().animation(.none)
                
                HatchedShap(dis: 30.0, move: move)
                    .stroke(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5.0))
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if (move == 3) { move = 0}
                        else { move = 3 }
                    }
            }
            .animation((move != 0) ? Animation.linear(duration: 1.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false) : Animation.linear(duration: 1.0), value: move)
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why, but your shape does not like to have the `move` value changed back and forth. Even removing the ternary for the animation, when you change it from 3 to 0 to 3 again, the animation stutters.

I propose two views that are rendered in sync, one animated, one not. Simply have the opposite `.opacity` so when one is visible, the other is transparent. You will notice that `move` is not changed after the first change in an `.onAppear()` to start the animation. Click on the Gif to view the output:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var move: CGFloat = 0
    @State var pause = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Text(String(describing: move)).bold().animation(.none)
                
                HatchedShap(dis: 30.0, move: move)
                    .stroke(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5.0))
                    .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 1.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: move)
                    .opacity(!pause ? 1 : 0)
                    // This is the paused view
                    .overlay(HatchedShap(dis: 30.0, move: move)
                                .stroke(Color.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5.0))
                                .opacity(pause ? 1 : 0)
                    )
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        pause.toggle()
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        move = 3
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, I don't know why the stutter occurs in the shape's animation when `move` is switched several times. That would be worth looking into.

Comment: But did you read my question that I am looking for pause and resume? Also did you run my codes? my codes works better than your current answer that you mixing 2 HatchedShap for unknown reason, but after all your codes does not deliver pause and resume goal! So what are you trying to answer here? Also I would say very bad coding with `opacity` Animation would be running on pause with opacity of zero! and in the pause the move value is became zero! which is show the wrong method as well. the move value could be between 0...3 depending on when user tap!

Comment: I did run your code. That is how I came up with understanding that your shape does not animate well with stops and starts. I am sure you noticed that in your testing. If you noticed, there is no animation on the `.overlay` so the value of `move` is irrelevant. Also, SwiftUI is very good at determining what needs to be updated or not. A transparent view does not need updating, so the fact that it is "running" is not using resources. The animation pauses for the user, just not in the way that you desire.

Comment: With all respect to you and your time, your answer is not what I am looking, I do not think that your answer even close to right answer. :) but thanks again. ;) PS: You said: "A transparent view does not need updating" that is not true! re-check it for yourself. A view is a view what ever is about opacity of it, it will use cpu resources.